# i cant use pictures in main activity.cs that i upload to the project from my computer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i tried to upload many pictures as .png or .jpg and change the name of each picture but with no avail
and it says no issues find but when i run the program it said its a binary file instead of text file

the output error is Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS2015  'E:\my programms\repos3\My first app\My first app\imageresourse1\red.png' is a binary file instead of a text file   My first app    E:\my programms\repos3\My first app\My first app\CSC    1   Active
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xh4ZG.png)

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images!!!

Comment: Please edit your question to contain formatted text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs2015), the error means:

> 'file' is a binary file instead of a text file
>
> A file was passed to the compiler that was a binary file. The compiler
> expects a source code file.

The error is caused by **red.png** instead of `mypick.jpg`.

Please check if the `red.png` is a valid png image and I think the solution is **remove** the `red.png` from drawable folder.

The `red.png` looks different from other images as there is a small transparent triangle there:

[image]